# xpath exp cannot be located in parent view

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to modify a template of an theme that we are using on our Odoo project. I'm trying to get the element using xpath expression and then replacing it but it is showing that it can't locate it in the parent view. I'm attaching the original view and my modification below.

This is the parent view or the original view/template:

```
<template id="as_product_base_slider_04">
    <div class="as-product-card as-product-card-04">
        <form action="/shop/cart/update" method="post" class="as_color_variant as-product-card-form">
            <t t-set="combination" t-value="product.sudo()._get_first_possible_combination()"/>
            <t t-set="combination_info" t-value="product.sudo()._get_combination_info(combination, add_qty=add_qty or 1, pricelist=website.get_current_pricelist())"/>
            <t t-set="product_variant" t-value="product.env['product.product'].browse(combination_info['product_id'])"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()" t-nocache="The csrf token must always be up to date."/>
            <input name="product_id" t-att-value="product_variant.id" type="hidden"/>
            <!-- Product Img -->
            <div class="as-product-card-media">
                <div class="as-product-card-media-primary">
                    <a t-attf-href="/shop/{{slug(product.sudo())}}">
                        <img class="as_product_main_img" t-att-src="request.website.image_url(product,'image_1024')"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Hover Image -->
                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_hover_image') and product.hover_image" class="as-hover-image">
                    <a t-attf-href="/shop/{{slug(product.sudo())}}">
                        <img t-att-src="request.website.image_url(product,'hover_image')"/>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <t t-if="configuration.get('allow_label')">
                    <t t-call="theme_alan.product_label"/>
                </t>



                <div class="as-product-card-action">
                    <t t-if="configuration.get('allow_wishlist')">
                        <t t-nocache="The wishlist depends on the user and must not be shared with other users. As this rendering is in the loop, the product value is set in the template, we must retain the id of the product on which we are."
                        t-nocache-product_template_id="product.id">
                            <t t-set="in_wish" t-value="product._is_in_wishlist()"/>
                            <a t-if="product_variant" type="button" role="button" t-attf-class="as-pc-btn as-pc-wishlist o_add_wishlist #{'disabled' if in_wish else ''}" t-att-disabled='in_wish or None' title="Add to Wishlist" t-att-data-product-template-id="product.id" t-att-data-product-product-id="product_variant.id" data-action="o_wishlist"><span class="asi asi-heart" role="img" aria-label="Add to wishlist"></span></a>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                    <t t-if="configuration.get('allow_compare')">
                        <t t-set="categories" t-value="product.valid_product_template_attribute_line_ids._prepare_categories_for_display()"/>
                        <a t-if="product_variant and categories" type="button" role="button" class="as-pc-btn as-pc-compare d-none d-md-inline-flex o_add_compare" title="Compare" aria-label="Compare" t-att-data-product-product-id="product_variant.id" data-action="o_comparelist"><span class="asi asi-repeat"></span></a>
                    </t>
                    <t t-if="configuration.get('allow_quick_view')">
                        <span class="as-pc-btn as-pc-quick-view as_quick_view" t-att-data-product_tmpl_id="product.id"><i class="asi asi-eye"></i></span>
                    </t>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="as-product-card-body">

                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_rating') and product.rating_avg" class="as-pc-rating">
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <t t-esc="product.rating_avg"/>
                </div>

                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_brand_info') and product.product_brand_id" class="as-pc-brand">
                    <span t-esc="product.product_brand_id.name" />
                </div>

                <div class="as-pc-title">
                    <a t-attf-href="/shop/{{slug(product.sudo())}}" t-esc="product.name" />
                </div>

                <div t-if="not (request.env.user._is_public() and request.website.active_b2b_mode)" class="as-price as-pc-price">
                    <t t-call="website_sale.product_price"/>
                    <small t-if="combination_info['base_unit_price']"
                            class="ms-1 text-muted o_base_unit_price_wrapper d-none" groups="website_sale.group_show_uom_price">
                        <t t-call='website_sale.base_unit_price'/>
                    </small>
                </div>

                <!-- Color Variant -->
                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_color_variant')" class="as-color-variant as-pc-colors">
                    <t t-foreach="product.valid_product_template_attribute_line_ids" t-as="ptal">
                        <t t-if="ptal.attribute_id.display_type == 'color'">
                            <ul>
                                <li t-foreach="ptal.product_template_value_ids._only_active()" t-as="ptav" >
                                    <t t-if="ptav.pv_thumbnail != False">
                                        <label class="as_color_variant_img css_attribute_color_tag" t-attf-style="background-image: url({{request.website.image_url(ptav,'pv_thumbnail')}}); background-size: cover;">
                                            <span t-att-data-product-image="request.website.image_url(product,'image_1024')"
                                                    t-att-data-color-image="request.website.image_url(ptav,'pv_thumbnail')" >
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </t>
                                    <t t-else="">
                                        <label t-attf-style="background-color:#{ptav.html_color or ptav.product_attribute_value_id.name}" t-attf-class="css_attribute_color_tag">
                                        </label>
                                    </t>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                </div>

                <!-- Offer Timer -->
                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_offer_time')" class="as-offer-time as-pc-timer">
                    <div class="as_offer_timer" t-att-data-offer="product.sudo().product_variant_id._get_offer_timing(website.get_current_pricelist())"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Stock Info -->
                <div t-if="configuration.get('allow_stock_info')" id="out_of_stock_message" class="as-pc-message">
                    <t t-if="not product.sudo().product_variant_id.allow_out_of_stock_order and product.sudo().product_variant_id.free_qty &lt; 1">
                        <t t-if="product.sudo().product_variant_id.out_of_stock_message">
                            <span t-esc="product.sudo().product_variant_id.out_of_stock_message"/>
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <span>Out of stock</span>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                    <t t-elif="product.sudo().product_variant_id.show_availability and product.sudo().product_variant_id.free_qty &lt;= product.product_variant_id.available_threshold">
                        <span>Only Few Units left in stock.</span>
                    </t>
                </div>

                <div class="as-product-card-cart">
                    <t t-if="configuration.get('allow_add_to_cart') and not (request.env.user._is_public() and request.website.active_b2b_mode)">
                        <!-- disable on outof stock -->
                        <a role="button" id="as_add_to_cart"
                        t-attf-class="{{'d-none' if combination_info['prevent_zero_price_sale'] else 'as-pc-btn as-pc-cart-btn'}}"
                                aria-label="Shopping cart" title="Shopping cart">
                            <i class="asi asi-shopping-cart"/> <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </a>
                    </t>
                    <t t-elif="request.env.user._is_public() and request.website.active_b2b_mode">
                        <a role="button" href="/web/login" t-attf-class="as-pc-btn as-pc-cart-btn #{'as_login_popup' if request.website.active_login_popup else ''}" title="Login For Price">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"/> <span>Login For Price</span>
                        </a>
                    </t>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is what I initially tried:

```
<template id="barryJays_product_title" inherit_id="theme_alan.as_product_base_slider_04" name="BarryJays Custom Works: Product Title">
  <xpath expr='//div[@class="as-pc-title"]' position="replace">
      <div class="as-pc-title">
          <h3>
            <a t-attf-href="/shop/{{slug(product.sudo())}}" t-esc="product.name" />
          </h3>
      </div>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

When that didn't work I tried this:

```
<template id="barryJays_product_title" inherit_id="theme_alan.as_product_base_slider_04" name="BarryJays Custom Works: Product Title">
  <xpath expr='//div//form//div[@class="as-product-card-body"]//div[@class="as-pc-title"]' position="replace">
      <div class="as-pc-title">
          <h3>
            <a t-attf-href="/shop/{{slug(product.sudo())}}" t-esc="product.name" />
          </h3>
      </div>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

But that also gives the same error, which is this (the path varies):

```
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1613, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 1810, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 149, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 699, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-80>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 76, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 678, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 615, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 485, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 373, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 230, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 749, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 709, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError(msg) from None  # Restart with "--log-handler odoo.tools.convert:DEBUG" for complete traceback
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:24
Error while validating view:

Element '<xpath expr="//div//form//div[@class=&#34;as-product-card-body&#34;]//div[@class=&#34;as-pc-title&#34;]">' cannot be located in parent view

View error context:
{'file': 'c:\\program '
         'files\\odoo\\server\\addons\\solorv_custom_works\\views\\templates.xml',
 'line': 2,
 'name': 'BarryJays Custom Works: Product Title',
 'view': ir.ui.view(3952,),
 'view.model': False,
 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(97,),
 'xmlid': 'barryJays_product_title'}


The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/1931-f71b37c/web.assets_backend.min.js:967:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/1931-f71b37c/web.assets_backend.min.js:975:13)
```

Any idea what would be the correct xpath expression for this? I'm trying to replace the full ac-pc-title div.

Comment: I have tested the XML Input with the expression you initially tried in a XPath Tester website and it works fine. Are you sure there is not another template that inherits `theme_alan.as_product_base_slider_04` and removes that div?

Comment: @Tiki, Yes, I'm sure about that. One of the ways I ensured it was by after the page loads I tried browser $x method. So on the browser console, I have inserted this expression: 
`$x('//div//form//div[@class="as-product-card-body"]//div[@class="as-pc-title"]');` and it returned the matched elements as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully the XPath expression. The error log shows `//a` at the end of the expression

If you apply the first expression, then any other XPath targetting `a` inside `div[@class="as-pc-title"]` will fail and raise an error

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot to remove the //a from the error log, I was actually trying with targeting that <a> as well that is inside of the as-pc-title log, must've pasted the error log from that. But as you can see, there's an <a> inside the as-pc-title, so if my expression was this: `//div//form//div[@class="as-product-card-body"]//div[@class="as-pc-title"]//a`, that should've worked, no?

Comment: Of course, if the template was not altered. If the `a` tag is moved inside `h3` like in your first example, Odoo will raise the above error

Answer (score 0):

Just change the div[@class="as-pc-title"] at the end of your expression to
div[@class=as-pc-title] (remove "")